# Feature for Maching Learning(SVM) in High Frequecy Order Book?

Tags: high-frequency, algorithmic-trading, machine-learning

I am trying to implement machine learning to predict the movement of bid and ask price but is unable to find the proper feature for training set. I am using Support Vector Machine for binary classification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Features could include:

- Bid-ask spread
- Bid-ask volume imbalance
- Signed transaction volume

The sign in the Signed transaction volume is positive if the buyer has issued a market order and negative if the seller issued a market order.

A great introductory plain English paper on high frequency trading machine learning applications can be found [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/papers/KearnsNevmyvakaHFTRiskBooks.pdf).

A good blog post with information relevant to the subject can be found [here](http://epchan.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-useful-is-order-flow-and-vpin.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but for creating training set,how will i generate labels for binary classification with given order depth.

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to predict. If you are trying to predict an upward movement, then Y could be a binary flag reflecting whether some measure of price increased by a selected amount in the next _ seconds.

Comment: I am trying to predict the direction of movement of Last trade price using binary flag .. but the problem is LTP can also be same so what i must do .I have to binary classify that data i.e either higher or lower..